# Как вызвать процедуру по условию?

Tags: mysql

Как правильно вызвать процедуру если найдена запись в таблице?

что то вроде такого:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1) THEN myProc()
```

`UPDATE`

под процедурой имел ввиду вызов `SIGNAL`

```
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'An error occurred';
```

Answer (score 1):

Скорее что-то вроде `$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1";` а потом

```
if ($query != false) {
    function myProc() {
    // Some code 
    };
};
```

**Нашел немного инфы** [Ответ на вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167576/check-if-table-exists-in-sql-server)

Comment: Автор вопроса, видимо, имеет ввиду использование хранимой  процедуры в MySQL

Answer (score 1):

```
IF ( SELECT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM test1
    WHERE ,,,
 ) ) THEN ,,,
```

Comment: а так можно в MYSQL ?